# claws email change sort order to show latest email at the top

Tags: claws-mail

Every time I open Claws email it always shows the screen with the bottom email highlighted. I can change the order so that it is either the oldest or most recent email but cannot find a way so that Claws opens showing the top email which I would like to be the most recent. Each time I have to scroll through the page ...Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had suffered with the same issue.  You need to go to *preferences-> Display -> Summaries*. 
There go to tab *Message list* and click on the button *Set message selection when entering a folder*.

There you have options how you would like to set it.

Here is the default settings:

[image]

I have removed most of them and used *newest email in the list*.  That would mean that the newest received email in the list is selected.